# Excel VBA - Range returns nothing

Tags: vba, excel

The following code will look for a cell containing `5/7 binnen 4h` and when it finds the cell it will copy the value of cell I on the same row to a different cell. Now there are a few cases when this text can't be found and I get an error. How could I handle this error?

```
Dim FoundRange As Range
Set FoundRange = Cells.Find("5/7 binnen 4h")
Range("I" & EmptyCell + 2).Value = Cells(FoundRange.Row, 9).Value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim FoundRange As Range
Set FoundRange = Cells.Find("5/7 binnen 4h")
If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
  Range("I" & EmptyCell + 2).Value = Cells(FoundRange.Row, 9).Value
Else
  'you might want to do something if it is not found (msgbox...)
End If
```

Comment: Omg quite easy if you know it! Thanks a bunch!